# If the Grid value is more than 10, Grid functionality not working in JSPlumb

Tags: grid, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb for my flow chart development. I am setting grid as 20,20 on binding draggable. grid is not working as I expected. If i set 10, 10 its working fine.

code :

instance.draggable(element, { grid:[10, 10] });